Renormalization verse dimensional regularization
I am trying to learn QFT for fun, well past college age and have never sat in a college classroom.  I understand counter terms, and how they re-normalize the Lagrangian fairly well. I understand a little bit better dimensional regularization. However, where I get confused is that it seems that in the one-loop diagrams there are times, when renormalization is used via counter terms, and there are times when dimensional regularization are used and that they are not used together for calculating scattering amplitudes for the one-loop diagrams. Is it correct to say that only one of these is used when dealing with one-loop diagrams, but that one would still use counter terms for renormalization for the actual Lagrangian?

Dimensional regularization is used to regulate the divergences. Counterterms are used to renormalize the divergences. Both of these together remove divergences in QFT.
